# Flattening folder structure

Tags: bash, shell-script, rename

I have this folder structure:

```
├── foo1
│   ├── bar1.txt
│   └── bar2.txt
├── foo2
│   ├── bar3.txt
│   └── bar4 with a space.txt
└── foo3
    └── qux1
        ├── bar5.txt
        └── bar6.txt
```

that I would like to flatten into this, with an underscore between each folder level:

```
├── foo1_bar1.txt
├── foo1_bar2.txt
├── foo2_bar3.txt
├── foo2_bar4 with a space.txt
├── foo3_qux1.bar6.txt
└── foo3_qux1_bar5.txt
```

I've looked around and I haven't found any solution that work, mostly I think because my problem has two particularities: there might be more than one folder level inside the root one and also because some files might have spaces.

Any idea how to accomplish this in bash? Thanks!

**Edit**: Running gleen jackman proposed answer I get this:

[image]

There are two underscores for the first level folder. Any idea how to either avoid this or just rename it so that is just one underscore? Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
find */ -type f -exec bash -c 'file=${1#./}; echo mv "$file" "${file//\//_}"' _ '{}' \;
```

remove `echo` if you're satisfied it's working. Don't worry that the echo'ed commands don't show quotes, the script will handle files with spaces properly.

If you want to remove the now empty subdirectories:

```
find */ -depth -type d -exec echo rmdir '{}' \;
```

Comment: Hey. That's awesome! Thanks. That did the trick almost entirely. I'm just having a minor issue, which is I'm getting `foo1__qux1_bar5.txt`, two underscores in the first folder level that is. Tried messing with your bash line but nothing seemed to work. Maybe I need to add something?

Comment: @nunos, I can't reproduce that behaviour

Comment: Really? Weird. I just updated my answer with some more info. Can you please take a look? Thanks.

Comment: huh. OK, change `"${file//\//_}"` to `"${file//+(/)/_`, and if this is a script, `shopt -s extglob`

Comment: I had the problem with the two underscores as well. Unfortunately, changing the command like you suggested did not work for me. I did find this answer on AskDifferent however: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/254224/122152

According to the answer, macOS might be using BSD find. A workaround can be to use findutils. It can be installed using homebrew with `brew install findutils` and then using `gfind` instead of `find`. This worked for me.

Comment: `find` can remove empty dirs natively: `find */ -type d -empty -delete` (without `-exec`)

Answer (score 5):

Using perl's rename :

```
find . -depth -type f -exec rename 's@(?<!\.)/@_@g' -- {} \;
```

#### OUTPUT

```
$ find -type f
./foo2_bar4 whit a space.txt
./foo3_qux1_bar6.txt
./foo2_bar3.txt
./foo3_qux1_bar5.txt
./foo1_bar2.txt
./foo1_bar1.txt
```

#### NOTE

- I use a [negative look behind](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) `(?<!\.)` to don't touch the first `./`
- I keep the empty dirs, feel free to :

  `find . -depth -type d -exec rm {} \;`

[image: warning] **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

If you run the following command (`GNU`)

```
$ file "$(readlink -f "$(type -p rename)")"
```

and you have a result like

```
.../rename: Perl script, ASCII text executable
```

and not containing:

```
ELF
```

then this seems to be the right tool =)

If not, to make it the default (usually already the case) on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --set rename /path/to/rename
```

(replace `/path/to/rename` to the path of your `perl's rename` command.

---

If you don't have this command, search your package manager to install it or [do it manually](https://metacpan.org/module/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL)

---

Last but not least, this tool was originally written by Larry Wall, the Perl's dad.

Comment: ... `-type d -exec rmdir `... ?

Comment: I don't seem to have rename available.. How exactly can I get it and is this normally available in a UNIX system? Thanks.

Comment: @nunos It's a Perl script. It's available under the name `perl-rename` in Arch Linux, and `prename` in Debian-based systems.

Comment: Added `rename` explanations

Answer (score 1):

with [`pax`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pax.html)...

```
pax -Xrwls '|/|_|g' */ "$PWD"
```

That will create a hardlink in the current directory to all files in its child directories with a `_` substituted for `/`. You can then inspect the results and remove all child directories with...

```
rm -rf */
```

...once you have verified the results are to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below command.

```
$ find -type f -exec bash -c 'mv $0 $(echo $0|sed "s/\//_/2")' {} \;
```

Above command will move the files and the directory will remain which can be removed later.

```
$ ls
foo1_bar1.txt  foo1_bar2.txt  foo2_bar3.txt  foo2_bar4.txt  foo3_bar5.txt  foo3_bar6.txt
```